# How do I get rid of water streaks on my bathroom wall?

Tags: bathroom, ceiling, cleaning, mold

So the walls in my bathroom have streaks all over them. They've been building up over time and is getting worse. The wall over the shower in particular looks pretty bad. Does anyone know how I can get rid of them? I tried spraying Clorox Bleach spray but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Anyways, I'm open to suggestions. [image]

Comment: use vinegar on it

Answer (score 2):

What that needs is a good scrubbing with warm soapy water. If the paint comes off because it is old or because it is no longer durable enough to survive a good scrubbing... then it needed repainting anyway. Use a high quality gloss or semi-gloss paint if you do it.

Comment: I agree that it might be two late for this paint and a good scrubbing may be needed or a quick wipe down with toluene, but that will remove some of the paint. The cause is two much humidity, make sure your fan is working and clean so it can pull the moisture out and not cause this problem in the first place.

Comment: Toluene in a residential bathroom? TSP would be a better choice and significantly easier on his sinuses and family. IMHO, using toluene in a closed area where the exhaust fan obviously can't even dump moist air is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The streaks are actually strips of "clean" or at least cleaner than the surroundings.

Unless adjacent to a kitchen, or the room used by smokers the dirt is unlikely to have an oil component.  Try the following:

- Hot water (as hot as you can stand with kitchen gloves on)  and laundry detergent.  This is generally good for the mix of dust and water that is the usual problem with walls.
- Hot water and TSP if the surface is greasy or smoke stained.

If these don't work

- Warm water and ammonia.  Tough on eyes and nose while working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Bleach works the best.

I use bleach all the time. Spray and leave it, do not scrub or wipe off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming, but it's best if you don't SHOUT in your answers. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Bleach is helping but it kinda looks like a lost cause. https://i.imgur.com/rPkEq4F.jpg